# Creating dynamic subdomains from url parameters in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on project where i have a url for example (https://example.com/index.php?country=usa).
I wanted this url to rewrite on sub-domain dynamically like https://usa.example.com (Without creating subdomains on cpanel). 
As soon as i open https://usa.example.com, it should fetch data from /index.php?country=usa.

I have added DNS for that purpose
A Record | Host: * | Pointing to server IP address.

Also i have tried below .htaccess code which i found online while searching the solution from last 2 days.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?country=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?country=%1
```

when I hit usa.example.com or uk.example.com i get 404 error.

I am confused either its working on not because no subdomain folder is created and no error_log i am getting in php. I am not familiar with htaccess. Please help.

Comment: Have you enabled the consideration of such distributed configuration files at all? See the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation for that.

Comment: What does your http server's error log file contain for those requests?

Comment: @arkascha there are no recent errors for those htaccess codes.

Comment: @arkascha are those above htaccess codes are valid for creating dynamic subdomains from url parameters.?

Comment: Sure that code is valid, that is not the question. What I asked is whether that code gets considered at all. You did not respond to that questions ...

Comment: To test that I suggest that you implement a definite syntax error into that configuration file. If you then make a request and you still do not get any entry in your http serverÄs error log file, than you know that the file does note get considered at all by the http server.

Comment: @arkascha i made typo mistake on htaccess code, i didn't received any logs on error panel.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
There are few steps to be followed.

1. Creating a wildcart subdomain which is important rather then just using htaccess.
   goto subdomain of your cpanel -> enter * in subdomain -> choose your directory as public_html
2. Check your zone editor for A record created or not. If you are using cloud flare service then add A record.
3. Use of HTACCESS code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?country=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?country=%1
```

You are done.

Comment: So where is the difference to what you already did before according to what you wrote in the question?

Comment: Also it is unclear what the first `RewriteRule` is meant to do. And why you do not need any flags for your second `RewriteRule`.

Comment: in addition I'd say you also want to add exceptions for the "www" variants of those host names. With the current setup you would process requests to `/index.php?country=www` ...